# Suppress the terminal output of a Python command

Tags: python, exception, output

```
try: var_sigma
except: print "Not defined."
```

This code prints the value of `var_sigma` if it's defined, but I want it to print nothing at all. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This code doesn't print anything if `var_sigma` is defined.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the `print` with `pass`:

```
try: var_sigma
except: pass
```

Although it might be better to rethink your design.  What will happen if you then try to use the variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    print var_sigma
except:
    print "Not defined."
```

The above would print `var_sigma` if it were defined. But your code sample does not do that, it does nothing if it is defined, and if its not defined, it prints something.

If you simple wanted to check whether `var_sigma` exists, then you could do the following:

```
try:
    assert isinstance(var_sigma, object)
except AssertionError:
    pass
```